# How many maximum app run in background at a time in android phone

Tags: android

How many applications can run in background at a time in android phone?

Comment: The amount of maximum apps allowed to run on a device without affective speed or response time would be in direct correlation with the available memory of each individual phone. A phone with 2gb of ram can run more visible and background than say a phone with 512mb ram.

Comment: Why do you need to know?  Android takes care of it.

Answer (score 3):

It depends on your phone RAM. 
if there is no space for other running applications then android kill background application.

Comment: For 512 RAM max 16 services runs in background

Answer (score 0):

I agree fully with Sumit Pathak an like to add that you can go to developer options and set the amount of maximal background processes :)